# QSFP-DD to 8x 10G SFP+

Tags: optical-fibre, network-interface

I am trying to use a QSFP-DD port on an FPGA to breakout and interface with 4 or 8 SFP+ ports. I am curious if this is possible. From my research online, it seems like this all depends on the module you're using (QSFP+ for 10G, QSFP28 for 25G).

I researched online and there seem to be QSFP-DD to 8 SFP cables. The issue is that the SFP side doesn't specify if its SFP+ or SFP28. It seems like SFP+ and SFP28 support two different rates (10 and 25 respectively). I've tried emailing the vendor, but they just say the cable can support both speeds which seems to contradict everything I read online. The FPGA spec says it can handle 8x 10/25, but my issue seems to be knowing how/if it can breakout to the 8 links? Has anyone ever dealt with this issue or know how I may get my solution to work?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got an authorative answer from the supplier. It's just a passive cable. It supports both.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My concern is that all documentation online seems to contradict that, so I fear the vendor is just trying to sell a cable or just reading from the catalog. Online, all documentation says QSFP28 cant break out into 10G links, but you can plug in a QSFP+ module into QSFP28 port for 10 G. My scenario is that I'm somewhere in the middle.